# How I can write C promgraming block letter separates function?

Tags: c, function

Can you help me for C programming that about, Write a c program to print "hello" using “#” in big block letters by creating a separate function,I don't know what I need to write for the new function,Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pleaes do not post pictures of code. Instaed insert your code directly as formatted text into your question. You can use the edit button below your question.

Comment: You are supposed to write a separate function. You only added blocks using `{ }` but no function.

Comment: So what the new function that I should to add?

Comment: You are supposed to write a function to print "HELLO". An obvious name candidate would be `print_hello` and the content is to do all the printing stuff.

Comment: Have a think about how you will treat the 'L' (needed twice), or if then asked to print, say 'HEEL'.

Comment: write printing functions for each letter then call them in the correct order to print "hello"

Comment: example function to print the letter 'H': `void printH()
{
 for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
  puts("#   #");
 }

 putchar(' ');

 for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
 {
  putchar('#');
 }

 putchar('\n');

 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
  puts("#   #");
 }
}`

Comment: If you want to print horizontally then it's simplest to draw each character into a large buffer, say 50 x 10 char, then print the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Best I can do with this is taking some inspiration from the 1602LCD world.
Now this isn't very pretty but it gets the job done, I leave the optimization and error handling to you.
You can generate custom bit maps with this https://maxpromer.github.io/LCD-Character-Creator/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t bitmap[] = {
  0x1B,
  0x1B,
  0x1B,
  0x1F,
  0x1F,
  0x1B,
  0x1B,
  0x1B
};

void print(uint8_t* p);
void printBits(size_t const size, void const * const ptr);

int main(){
    print(bitmap);
    return 0;
}

void print(uint8_t* p){
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        printBits(sizeof(uint8_t), p++);
    }
}

void printBits(size_t const size, void const * const ptr){
    unsigned char *b = (unsigned char*) ptr;
    unsigned char byte;
    int i, j;
    
    for (i = size-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (j = 4; j >= 0; j--) {
            byte = (b[i] >> j) & 1;
            if(byte != 0){
                printf("#");
            }
            else{ 
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Outputs:

```
## ##
## ##
## ##
#####
#####
## ##
## ##
## ##


...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

Comment: It seems that the OP just learned what functions are. Therefore I assume this solution is likely beyond the expecirence level of the OP.

Comment: My assumption was that OP could take some inspiration to get moving on OP's project. This is just one semi poor way of doing it. As I state, refining this is left to OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can create it like this: Just to show you,I have created "h" using "#" by creating a separate function - `ft_print`. Then I am calling the function from the main.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void    ft_print(void)
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("#\n");
    printf("#\n");
    printf("#\n");
    printf("#\n");
    printf("######\n");
    printf("#    #\n");
    printf("#    #\n");
    printf("#    #\n");
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    ft_print();

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: That's a lovely chair :)

Comment: OMG,I can get it already,Thank you for your help a lot

Comment: You're welcome. Happy coding :)